# Which jpcap library to use?

Tags: jpcap

I'm new to jpcap and I have been looking for a most useful, the best, the most widely used, the most popluar jpcap library?

i came across these jpcap libraries.

The one on http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/ ?

, the one on http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/ ?

, the one from github?
, and the one from jnetpcap.com/node

is there any better jpcap library or there is a standard jpcap library provided by Oracle?

I want to know which is the most useful, the best, the most widely used, the most popluar jpcap library?

Answer (score 0):

I use [this version of JPCAP](https://github.com/mgodave/Jpcap). The other versions hosted on SourceForge or GitHub `jpcap/jpcap` are similar, but don't support sending packets (they only **capture** packets).

Answer (score 0):

Well all of these libraries are just wrappers making native library calls. The main library is libpcap which is written in C. All these libraries like jpcap and jnetpcap just use libpcap underneath. I have used both jpcap and jnetpcap and through personal experience i would suggest that you use jnetpcap as it is much easier to use, has a good documentation with examples and it has a recently updated version. You can download it from http://jnetpcap.com